# Every response data size from server to client in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

How can i know about the size of data being transfered between server to client in asp.net
Even for ajax postbacks...

Comment: is there any method like trace="true" in asp.net

Comment: I am trying to achieve this exact thing in IIS too, to no avail. I have done it in lighttpd using `mod_status` and parsing it in PHP. This gives me connection states, times and data being transfered. Very cool. No such luck with M$ junk.

Answer (score 0):

You can check response size in the IIS log file.

Comment: i need to check more frequently..like on every ajax call, how much data is being transfered

Comment: Well in IIS log you can see all requests details (providing logging in on) which hit the IIS server.